# How to add spacing between columns?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two columns:

```
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
```

How can I add a space between them?

The output would simply be two columns right next to each other taking up the whole width of the page. Say the width was set to `1000px` then each div would be `500px` wide.

If I wanted a `100px` space between the two how could I achieve this automatically with Bootstrap: the `div`s sizes would become `450px` each to compensate for the spacing.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

You can achieve spacing between columns using the [`col-md-offset-*` classes, documented here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-offsetting). The spacing is consistent so that all of your columns line up correctly. To get even spacing and column size I would do the following:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5"></div>
  <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2"></div>
</div>
```

In Bootstrap 4 use: `offset-2` or `offset-md-2`

Comment: that would work when I want to stick with the default column sizes, what if I want a specific size of spacing, rather than offsetting the columns?

Comment: In this case I would recommend using the provided mixins to adjust column gutters: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-less - Bootstrap doesn't do what you ask in the question, it can't "adjust" grid widths to account for extra spacing in between because it is based on a pixel grid.

Comment: Ben, is it wise to suggest adding non semantic empty divs to the HTML in order to add grid gutters?

Comment: George - you have the offset classes for this. But if you find the built in gutters insufficient then you might want to try compiling your own version of bootstrap, either from less or sass depending on your preferences. You can then modify the column widths and gutters to match your website. Adding empty divs isn't really bad though, what is important is coming up with something that you (and/or your team) can use consistently; if empty divs is the way that you achieve that then it's fine; remember that your markup is meant to be read by your developers, not your end users.

Comment: This post is not an answer at all, it creates a gap much bigger than asked.

Comment: In Bootstrap 4, this is offset-md-2 or offset-2

Answer (score 383):

I was facing the same issue; and the following worked well for me.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="col-md-12">
        Some Content.. 
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="col-md-12">
        Some Second Content.. 
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will automatically render some space between the 2 divs.

[image]

Comment: mainly due to gutter widths.

Comment: "gutter widths" refers to the spacing in padding and margins defined in the core of bootstrap's grid system. In short, adding in a second div with `col-xs-12` is the same as adding a div with `width:100%; padding:0px 15x;`

Comment: @sixty4bit could you share your code; may be I can help you.

Comment: that'd be great @Utpal-UrBestPal, thanks! here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/davidcpell/8d344ff18d5d188115c0ff9ba6ef7d14

Comment: Hi @sixty4bit, it is working; to see the space kindly give border around col-12 class. Use bootstrap CDN http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: If you're using this fix and it's not working, read why it works in @mix3d 's explanation and you'll understand what you're doing wrong.

Comment: This doesn't maintain the spacing when the columns stack :(

Comment: excellent solution because this is so simple and feels right when you are not bound to use specific widths to child divs/contents. Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Good sollution but this doesnt just add spacing between the divs. It also adds it at the sides.

Comment: Great solution! As someone mentioned it doesn't just add spacing between the cols but was just what I needed. Much better than the above offset-solution, that leaves a oddly looking space between the cols.

Comment: This causes the columns to no longer have the same height (as shown in the screenshot).

Comment: Hi @JonSchneider no that is not true. I deliberately had created to of them with different heights as that was what I needed.

Answer (score 82):

I know I'm late to the party, but you could try spacing the boxes with padding.

```
<div class="col-md-6 box">
        <div class="inner">Hello</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 box">
        <div class="inner">Hello</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
.box .inner {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Have a go at it

Comment: Not really because you cannot use `row-eq-height` with it

Answer (score 34):

you can use background-clip and box-model with border proprety

```css
.box{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  background-clip:padding-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 box"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 box"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The best hack I found in all the answers, thanks man it solved my issue as in my case this boxes comes dynamic from database.

Comment: this is great! thanks, i can't change tags elements in my code, and this resolve changing only css, thank you!

Answer (score 14):

I have had similar issues with space between columns. The root problem is that columns in bootstrap 3 and 4 use padding instead of margin. So background colors for two adjacent columns touch each other.

I found a solution that fit our problem and will most likely work for most people trying to space columns and maintain the same gutter widths as the rest of the grid system.

This was the end result we were going for

[image]

Having the gap with a drop shadow between columns was problematic. We did not want extra space between columns. We just wanted the gutters to be "transparent" so the background color of the site would appear between two white columns.

this is the markup for the two columns

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="raised-block">
            <h3>Facebook</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="raised-block">
            <h3>Tweets</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.raised-block {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: -0.625rem; // for us 0.625rem == 10px
    padding-left: 0.625rem;
    padding-right: 0.625rem;
}
@media (max-width: 33.9em){ // this is for our mobile layout where columns stack
    .raised-block {
        margin-left: -0.625rem;
    }
}
.row [class^="col-"]:first-child>.raised-block {
    // this is so the first column has no margin so it will not be "indented"
    margin-left: -0.625rem;
}
```

This approach does require an inner div with negative margins just like the "row" class bootstrap uses. And this div, we called it "raised-block", must be the direct sibling of a column

This way you still get proper padding inside your columns. I have seen solutions that appear to work by creating space, but unfortunately the columns they create have extra padding on either side of the row so it ends up making the row thinner that the grid layout was designed for. If you look at the image for the desired look, this would mean the two columns together would be smaller than the one larger one on top which breaks the natural structure of the grid.

The major drawback to this approach is that it requires extra markup wrapping the content of each columns. For us this works because only specific columns needed space between them to achieve the desired look.

Answer (score 14):

According to Bootstrap 4 [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/) you should give the parent a negative margin `mx-n*`, and the children a positive padding `px-*`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row mx-n5">
  <div class="col px-5">
    <div class="p-3 border bg-light">Custom column padding</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col px-5">
    <div class="p-3 border bg-light">Custom column padding</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What worked best for me (vertical spacing between rows) was `<div class="row mt-n4">` and `<div class="col-3 pt-4">`.

Answer (score 12):

This will allow a space between the two columns and obviously if you want to change the default width you can go for mixins to modify the default bootstrap width. Or, you can give the width using the inline CSS style.

```
<div class="col-md-5 pull-left"></div>
<div class="col-md-5 pull-right"></div>
```

Comment: The semantic of this is not exactly what @Muhammed is asking. You are adding a change in the order of the columns with pull-left, pull-right.

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve spacing between columns using the col-xs-* classes,within in a  col-xs-* div coded below. The spacing is consistent so that all of your columns line up correctly. To get even spacing and column size I would do the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <div class="col-md-12 well">
            Some Content..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <div class="col-md-12 well">
            Some Second Content..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <div class="col-md-12 well">
            Some Second Content..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <div class="col-md-12 well">
            Some Second Content..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <div class="col-md-12 well">
            Some Second Content..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <div class="col-md-12 well">
            Some Second Content..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <div class="col-md-12 well">
            Some Second Content..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <div class="col-md-12 well">
            Some Second Content..
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Since you're using **bootstrap**, I guess you want to make the thing **responsive**. In that case you should'n use fixed sizes, in 'px' for example.

As a workaround to other solutions, I propose make both columns "col-md-5" instead of "col-md-6", and then in the parent element "row" that contains the columns, add the class "justify-content-between", which puts the free space in the middle, as you can check in the bootstrap doc [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment)

This solution is also valid for more than two columns adjusting the "col-md-x" of course

hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 6):

bootstrap 5 provides a more comfortable way to add gaps:

1. using `g-*` class to make cols/rows spacings equal
2. `gx-* gy-*` classes to make cols/rows spacings different

```
<div class="row g-2">
  <div class="col-6">...</div>
  <div class="col-6">...</div>
  <div class="col-6">...</div>
  <div class="col-6">...</div>
</div>
```

[image: example]

docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/

Answer (score 4):

Inside the col-md-?, create another div and put picture in that div, than you can easily add padding like so.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
     <div class="thumbnail">
       <img src="#"/>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="thumbnail">
       <img src="#"/>
     </div>
  </div>   
</div>

<style>
  thumbnail{
     padding:4px;
           }
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Bootstrap 4**, file custom.scss you can add following code:

```
$grid-gutter-width-base: 20px;

$grid-gutter-widths: ( xs: $grid-gutter-width-base, 
sm: $grid-gutter-width-base, 
md: $grid-gutter-width-base, 
lg: $grid-gutter-width-base, 
xl: $grid-gutter-width-base
);
```

by default $grid-gutter-width-base: 30px;

Comment: could you please elaborate it? it's not working for me

Comment: @SelvaGanapathi you have to recompile after changing these variables: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#customizing-the-grid

Comment: In Bootstrap 4, this is offset-md-2 or offset-2

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using Bootstrap, the **column-gap** property will be useful to implement.  [W3Schools Column-Gap for Bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-gap.asp)  has documentation on how this can be used.

- CSS:

```
.col-gap {
  column-gap: 2rem;
}
```

And for the HTML, have the class (**col-gap**) in the row div.
But also note this may throw off the spacing of the col-md-6 (or other sizes) so to compensate reduce the size for each column.
(i.e. col-md-6 -> col-md-5, even if there are only 2 columns)

- HTML:

```
    //Row
    <div class="row col-gap justify-content-center">
 
    //Col 1
        <div class="col-md-5 ms-3 card p-5">
            <p>Div 1</p>
        </div>

    //Col 2
        <div class="col-md-5 ms-3 card p-5">
            <p>Div 2</p>
        </div>          
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Bootstrap 4 - Separate columns using nested rows.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row bg-info p-3">

        <!-- left column -->
        <div class="col-8 ">
            <div class="col-12 bg-light p-3">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro error enim, perferendis rerum, sit laudantium alias esse quas quae mollitia illum suscipit veritatis distinctio facere officia ullam repellendus accusamus odio!
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- right column -->
        <div class="col-4 ">
            <div class="col-12 bg-light p-3">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro error enim, perferendis rerum, sit laudantium alias esse quas quae mollitia illum suscipit veritatis distinctio facere officia ullam repellendus accusamus odio!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe using the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57124328/6813732) provided by @estani is a more "classic" way to do this with bootstrap4 ?

Answer (score 2):

I had to figure out how to do this for 3 columns.  I wanted to round the corners of the divs and couldn't get the spacing to work.  I used margins.  In my case I figured for 90% of the screen to be filled in by the divs and 10% for margins:

html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="orange" class="col-md-4">
    <h1>Orange Div</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="green" class="col-md-4">
    <h1>Green Div</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="aqua" class="col-md-4">
    <h1>Aqua Div</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#orange {
    background-color:orange;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 2.5% 2.5% 0 2.5%;
    width:30%;
}
#green {
    background-color:green;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 2.5% 0 0 0;
    width:30%;
}
#aqua {
    background-color:#39F;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 2.5% 2.5% 0 2.5%;
    width: 30%;
}
```

To make it resize correctly for mobile devices, I had the CSS change the width from 30% to `width:92.5%;` under `@media (max-width:1023px)`

Answer (score 1):

Use bootstrap's `.form-group` class. Like this in your case:

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group"></div>
<div class="col-md-6 form-group"></div>
```

Comment: How a margin-bottom can be useful here?

Answer (score 1):

it's simple .. you have to add solid border right, left to col-* 
and it should be work ..:)

it looks like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF5ZV.png

HTML :

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-3" id="services_block">

     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3" id="services_block">

     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3" id="services_block">

     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3" id="services_block">

     </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
div#services_block {
   height: 355px;
   background-color: #33363a;
   border-left:3px solid white;
   border-right:3px solid white;
}
```

Comment: you don't use multiple ids on the same page, it's totally lack of knowledge of how to use css. Use classes instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just white border around wrap element

```
.padding-pls{
  border-left: 13px solid white;
  border-right: 13px solid white;
}
.row .col-md-6:first-child>.padding-pls {
  border-left: 0px solid white;
}
.row .col-md-6:last-child>.padding-pls {
  border-right: 0px solid white;
}
```

and first+last child no border

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-12 padding-pls">
          Keci
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-12 padding-pls">
          Keci
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is a little dated but I ran in to this same problem. Example of my html.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>            
</div>
```

In order to create space between the groups I overrode bootstrap's margin of -15px in my site.css file by reducing the negative margin by 5.

Here's what I did...

```
.form-group {
    margin-right: -10px;
}
```

I hope this helps somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

I needed one column on mobile and two columns from tablet portrait up, with equal spacing between them in the middle (also without any grid-added padding inside columns). Could be achieved using spacing utilities and omitting the number in `col-md`:

```html
    <div class="container-fluid px-0">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md mr-md-3" style="background-color: orange">
                <p><strong>Column 1</strong></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md ml-md-3" style="background-color: orange">
                <p><strong>Column 1</strong></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Bootstrap col slightly uses some spaces both to the left and right. I have just added a block element like div and set the border for the differences. Also, adding some extra padding or margin in that extra div will work perfectly..**

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<br><br>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 ">
            <div class="border border-danger ">
                <h2 class="text-center">1</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="border border-warning">
                <h2 class="text-center">2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap col slightly use some spaces both left and right. I have just added a block element like div and set border for the differences. also adding some extra padding or margin in that extra div will work perfectly

Comment: thanks for your comment, but can you please edit your answer and add that within the answer (to make it more usefull, and simpler to understand)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with Bootstrap alone. The space between columns is automatically added/maintained.
If you need to add a specific width between columns you can do this trick to simulate the space: https://jsfiddle.net/loginet/3rogbh9s/5/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="left-column">Left column</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="right-column">Right column</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.left-column {
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    background: white;
}

.right-column { 
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 50px; 
    background: white;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just adding a border the same color as the background using css? I'm new to this, so maybe there's a good reason not to, but it looked good when I tried it.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. If you need more information or clarification on a question, please use comments instead of answers.

Comment: If the background used an image/texture instead of solid color this would be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a particular width of spacing between columns, we have to set up `padding` in the standard Bootstrap's layout.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

/* Check breakpoint at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries */
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
  .space-100-px > .row > .col-md-6:first-child {
    padding: 0 50px 0 0; /* The first half of 100px */
  }
  .space-100-px > .row > .col-md-6:last-child {
    padding: 0 0 0 50px; /* The second half of 100px */
  }
}

/* The result will be easier to see. */ 
.space-100-px img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid space-100-px">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x100?text=Left" alt="Left">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x100?text=Right" alt="Right">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be useful..

```css
.list-item{
  margin-right:-10px;
   margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="list-item">
      <h2>Your name</h2> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="list-item"></div>
</div>
```

If use want to increase or decrease further margin in right side of the box then simply edit margin-right property of list-item.

**sample output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="col-md-12 no_padding header_row"></div>



    <div class="second_row">
        <div class="col-md-4 box_shadow"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 no_padding_right">
            <div class="col-md-12 box_shadow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    body{
    background:#F0F0F0;
}

.main_holder{
    min-height: 600px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    height: 600px;
}
.box_shadow{
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    background: white;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 500px;
}

.no_padding{
    padding: 0px !important;
}

.no_padding_right{
    padding-right: 0px !important;
}

.header_row{
    height: 60px;
    background: #00796B;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 1px rgba(143,140,143,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 1px rgba(143,140,143,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 1px rgba(143,140,143,1); 
}

.second_row{
    position: relative;
    width: 100% !important;
    top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: A bit prose about what and why might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="inner">
        <!-- Put the col-6 elements in the inner div -->
    </div>
</div>
```

This by default provides some padding inside the outer div the way you seem to need. Moreover you can also modify the padding using custom CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Way

```
.row div{
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}
```

Comment: incomplete example.

Answer (score 0):

## Bootstrap 4

Documentation says ([here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)):

> Rows are wrappers for columns. Each column has horizontal padding (called a gutter) for controlling the space between them. This padding is then counteracted on the rows with negative margins. This way, all the content in your columns is visually aligned down the left side.

So the right answer is: set `col`s' padding-left/right equal to minus your `row`'s margin-left/right. That simple.

```
#my-row {
  margin-left: -80px;
  margin-right: -80px;
}

#my-col {
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/frouo/pen/OqGaWN

[image: col with custom spacing]

Answer (score 0):

Create a class and use:

margin: 1.5em .5em;
max-width: calc(50% -  1em)!important;

Where 1em on the max-width is equal to the left/right margin added together.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card">
        Content one
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card">
        Content two
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Bootstrap v5.0** you can set gap with cssvariable:

```
.row {
  --bs-gutter-x: 100px; // column-gap
  --bs-gutter-y: 100px;  // row-gap
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these classes : **row, col-sm-4, mb-3, card, card-body, card-text**

```
<div *ngFor="let grade of grades">{{grade.gradeTitle}}
<hr>
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
    <div *ngFor="let level of getLevelsByGradeId(grade.gradeId)" class="col-sm-4 mb-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body card-content">
                <span class="card-text">{{level.levelTitle}}</span>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-trash text-red fa-xl"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.card-content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this works fine for me with default gutter width in bootstrasp 4. No extra css needed. The 2 sections evenly divided and the columns dont overflow to next row.

```
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="shadow card">
                    content here
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="shadow card">
                    content here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

This also one way of doing it and its works. Please check the following url https://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazk/ofgqm0sh/

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="bg-success">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="bg-warning">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Using margin-left is the way to go:

```
<div style="margin-left:-2px" class="col-md-6"></div>
<div style="margin-left:2px" class="col-md-6"></div>
```

works perfectly

Comment: No it doesn't that breaks responsiveness.

Answer (score -6):

With latest bootstrap version, you can use "cards"

Comment: Your answer needs further explanation. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer