# How to give margins within two col-sm-6 grid boxes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="container">
  <section class="eachmenu col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">    
    <h3 id="chicken">Chicken</h3>
    ...
  </section>
  <section class="eachmenu col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">    
    <h3 id="beef">Beef</h3>
    ...
  </section>
```

I want to give some margins between two boxes which are located in col-sm-6 each.

[image: I want some margins between them.]

I also want the length of two boxes matches well with the last col-sm-12 box.

[image: two boxes of col-sm-6 and one box of col-sm-16]

How I can do this? If i give margins like this,

```
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  section {
    margin-right: 2%;
  }
}
```

then the second box goes down..

[image: Giving some margins leads to breaking columns.]

Thanks for your support, I solved it!

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Our Menu</h2>
    <br><br>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="eachmenu">
        <h3>Chicken</h3>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="eachmenu">
        <h3>Beef</h3>
         ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="eachmenu">
        <h3>Sushi</h3>
           ...
      </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- container-->
```

also changed with css file..

```
.eachmenu {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  background-color: rgb(47, 218, 146);
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
}

/* START SM */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .eachmenu {
    margin-right: 2%; => I erased it (it didn't match when 6-6-12 }
}
/* End SM */
```

[image: sm-col-6 fits well.]

[image: (gave some padding here)]

and...

[image: two boxes of sm-col-6 and one box of sm-col-12 doesn't exactly fit but It seems fine]

(Edited)
(Erased margin-right:2% in media query => matches well now)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a user-defined gap between two Bootstrap columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806251/create-a-user-defined-gap-between-two-bootstrap-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using style on section is quite dangerous since it will affect *any* section of your code.
Better attribute a class and put it where you need.
Also, there's a `@media` attribute quite specific, which it's working only on width between 768 and 991px.

**EDIT**

I saw from the screenshot what you're aiming is to set a border, or maybe a color around that section. Usually you first set up the grid, or skeleton of your website, then inside you can play around. This is because otherwise you will fight forever with spacing.

```
  .right-space {
      margin-right: 2%;
  }
```

and

```
  <section class="eachmenu col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">   
   <div class="right-space">My content</div>
```

So as you can see, the section will define in which space we can move, then my div inside it will contain the border, the decoration and the content so it will adjust accordingly the bigger container.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I changed section tag to div tag. It works if I use col-sm-5 and col-sm-5.(col-sm-6 and col-sm-6 doesn't works well..) but I still wonder other way because two boxes and under-box doesn't match well..

Comment: I've updated my answer, try to give a look and let me know ;)

Comment: Oh I changed it by reading your support! <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="eachmenu"> and added 'margin-right' in eachmenu!

Comment: Great happy to help! If it solved your problem marked it as solved, so it will help other people as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`col-`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options) *class without a number* but the breakpoint (`.col-sm` , `.col-md` , `.col-lg` , `.col-xl` ) and also the `m`(for margins)  class with the breakpoint as well and the value you need. both your column are of the same size, built-in class should do without custom CSS (see equal column ).

possible example:

```css
section {
  background: gray;/* see us */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <section class="eachmenu col-md-12  my-2 col-sm   mr-sm-2 col-xs  mr-xs-2">
      <h3 id="chicken">Chicken</h3>
      ...
    </section>
    <section class="eachmenu col-md-12 col-sm  my-2 mx-md-0 ml-sm-2 col-xs  ml-xs-2">
      <h3 id="beef">Beef</h3>
      ...
    </section>
    <section class="eachmenu col-12 my-2 ">
      <h3 id="duck">Duck</h3>
      <p class="bg-info text-white p-1"> run in full page mode , then resize the window.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```