# How do I add a margin between bootstrap columns without wrapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My layout currently looks like this

[image: Current Layout]

In the center column, I want to add a small margin between each `Server` Div. But, if I add a margin to the CSS, it ends up line wrapping and looking like this

[image: Attempted Change]

```
<div class="row info-panel">
    <div class="col-md-4 server-action-menu" id="server_1">
        <div>
            Server 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 server-action-menu" id="server_2">
        <div>
            Server 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 server-action-menu" id="server_3">
        <div>
            Server 3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 server-action-menu" id="server_4">
        <div>
            Server 4
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 server-action-menu" id="server_5">
        <div>
            Server 5
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 server-action-menu" id="server_6">
        <div>
            Server 6
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 server-action-menu" id="server_7">
        <div>
            Server 7
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.server-action-menu {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0.2) 0%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 0) 100%);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border-radius:10px;
}

.info-panel {
    padding: 4px;
}
```

I attempted to add the margins by doing this

```
.info-panel  > div {
    margin: 4px;    
}
```

How can I add a margin to the DIVs so that they don't leave so much space on the right hand side?

Answer (score 202, accepted):

You should work with padding on the inner container rather than with margin. Try this!

HTML

```
<div class="row info-panel">
    <div class="col-md-4" id="server_1">
       <div class="server-action-menu">
           Server 1
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.server-action-menu {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0.2) 0%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 0) 100%);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: the thing inside the column behaves differently if you do this, for example inputs wont expand to fill the cell.

Comment: I think borders can damage this

Comment: Fixes the wrap problem, but hoses your borders, backgrounds etc.

Answer (score 83):

I was facing the same issue; and the following worked well for me:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            Set room heater temperature
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            Set room heater temperature
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will automatically render some space between the 2 divs.
[image]

Comment: This works great, especially when background colours matter. Also mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29576362/1998086).

Comment: But column directly inside a column is a bad practice, right?

Comment: This is a bad practice, I don't recommend that solution. Especially, this is not a better solution than a container div with class px-X

Comment: A container with px doesn't solve the problem as it fundamentally changes bkg colors and borders.

Answer (score 65):

If you do not need to add a border on columns, you can also simply add a transparent border on them:

```
[class*="col-"] {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: Nice trick, and if you can't use background-clip: padding-box (it's CSS3), set  borders with the same color of your page background ;)

Comment: Love this solution.

Comment: issue with this solution is it breaks all the other cols in the page that don't need the space

Comment: @PabloPazos of course, the solution need to be adapted to your own case. Just replace the generic `[class*="col-"]` by another selector to target the columns where you want to add margins.

Comment: Changing the behavior of column in CSS is also a bad practice. Don't do that !

Answer (score 25):

Change the number of `@grid-columns`. Then use `-offset`. Changing the number of columns will allow you to control the amount of space between columns. E.g.

**variables.less (approx line 294).**

```
@grid-columns:              20;
```

**someName.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">First column</div>
  <div class="col-md-13 col-md-offset-1">Second column</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ShaunLuttin instead of adding offset classes to all of your divs of all of your templates in order to make margin, isn't there a more global solution? Have the same problem over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26016396/add-gutter-margin-between-bootstrap-columns/26016735#26016735 but adding offset classes everywhere isn't really maintainable ..

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos You could use the `.make-md-column-offset()` mixin to do it. Also, consider playing with the `@grid-gutter-width` variable.

Answer (score 6):

The simple way to do this is doing a div within a div

```html
<div class="col-sm-4" style="padding: 5px;border:2px solid red;">
   <div class="server-action-menu" id="server_1">Server 1
   </div>
 </div>
<div class="col-sm-4" style="padding: 5px;border:2px solid red;">
   <div class="server-action-menu" id="server_1">Server 2
   </div>
 </div>
<div class="col-sm-4" style="padding: 5px;border:2px solid red;">
   <div class="server-action-menu" id="server_1">Server 3
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Mr. Flores. Inline style is rarely a viable solution for this kind of issue.

Comment: @Kiwad The inline styles are just to illustrate the effects clearly to viewers.

Comment: why exactly does this trick work to create space anyway? (it works btw, just curious)