# Divide a column into 2 parts in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a div with class "col-lg-9", inside that div there are two columns with a class of "col-lg-6" for each one. it works good but the issue is that there is no margin between the columns.

To see things visually, I've added a grey background to the main column. Notice how is no margin between the blue and the pink columns.

Please see the issue in this pic:
[image]

Live link:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35853519/basmaty-website/index.html

The code:

```
<div class="main col-lg-9">
    <div class="col-lg-6">

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">

    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a margin between bootstrap columns without wrapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010845/how-do-i-add-a-margin-between-bootstrap-columns-without-wrapping)

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood, but the question I have marked yours as a duplicate of should help. This answer suggests padding the  inner content: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19010988/2005759

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have different options, however, I'd recommend you to start with a basic thing for ALL options, which is this:

```
<div class="main col-lg-9 myHalfCol">
    <div class="col-lg-6">

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">

    </div>
</div>
```

Now you can target `.myHalfCol` without worrying about affecting any other `.col-lg-6` class

As for approaches, you can use the padding model, leaving everything as is just adding some padding at the sides, like this:

```
.myHalfCol .col-lg-6{padding:0 10px;}
```

**The margin model:**
Here you use real margins, so you need to take care of width.

```
.myHalfCol .col-lg-6{width:48%; margin:0 1% /* or auto */;}
```