# Bootstrap column full height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make two full height **bootstrap** columns like the example here : [Twitter bootstrap 3 two columns full height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089384/twitter-bootstrap-3-two-columns-full-height) 
But the problem is that it show me the first column content (`col-md-2`) after the second one content (`col-md-10`).

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<style type="text/css">



html,body,.m-container
{
    height:100%;
}
.m-container
{
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;


    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.row
{
    height: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}
.col-md-2 .no-float, .col-md-10 .no-float {
    float: none; 
}
.col-md-2
{
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    background: pink;
}
.col-md-10
{
    display: table-cell;
    background: yellow;
    float: none;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<header>Header</header>
<div class="m-container">
    <div class="row">
<!--  Data sources accordion  -->
<div class="col-md-2">
 <div class="well">I'm another well</div>
</div><!-- /end of col -->
        <!-- 
        Wall of panels 

         -->
<div class="col-md-10">


  <div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="well">I'm the first well</div>

</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="well">I'm the second well</div>

</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="well">I'm the third well</div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying without using `col-md-6` in the `col-md-10` part and it works, but i should use `col-md-6`
Someone have an idea why i have this problem?
Above the JSFiddle link to my code 
[JSFIDDLE Code](https://jsfiddle.net/dev_java/n3ehovwg/)

Comment: First - your HTML is not correct. It looks like m-container and it's first row are not closed. Add tabs and it will be clear. Second - by default total amout of bootstrap columns indexes is 12. Inside col-md-10 total amount is 18. Third - add div with row class inside col-md-10.

Comment: please indent your code, you will see a missing </div> before body.

Comment: Yeah i have a missing </div> i've correct it but isn't this the problem

Comment: @victor k  sorry i don't undrestand your remarks add a row inside col-md-10 will changing nothing

Comment: @victor k can you see this example please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956065/divide-a-column-into-2-parts-in-bootstrap-3