# Add margin between Bootstrap columns while removing it for 12-col-wide columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a customized version of Bootstrap v3 that adds percentage-paged margin-left between columns (gutter).

In order to have margin everywhere but the first column, I apply a rule which finds the first child of a row and resets its margin. This used to work back on Boostrap v2, but now with the multiple width classes applied on elements it doesn't work as well.

The reason is, when a col-*-12 is triggered, the element which was not a first child of a row, does not align with the rest of the divs in the left. (because it inherits the margin-left value)

In order to illustrate the problem, I made a plunker. http://embed.plnkr.co/t31Sc2cPvaIsSYVv7OIT/

You have to know that this is implemented in the context of a CMS with 20 different layouts so of course the solution should be generic.

Comment: What is it that you want to do?  Do you want to know how to change the gutter width but have the page still behave responsively in v.3? Or, are you committed to your approach and you want to see if there is a solution for this specific issue?

Comment: I want to find a smart way to reset margin-left to 0 for elements which take 100% of total width container.. While of course being responsive (that's the point of doing this anyway)

Comment: It's possible you're going to lots of trouble to do something Bootstrap already does... putting your cols in a .row removes the need to force negative margin in most cases, since .row offsets the padding with -15px margin. This way the content within left and right cols is right on the edge, but inside cols have padding intact. You obviously have lots going on, but it's possible implementing this will save you time and aggravation...

Comment: Yeah but when your divs go responsive mode the go under each other so rows don't behave as they did... Can you make a plunker fork if you think you have the solution, and I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem was simpler than I thought.

1. I moved the margin-left declarations inside the media queries:

   > ```
   > @media (min-width:579px) {
   >   .col-sm-1,
   >   .col-sm-2,
   >   .col-sm-3,
   >   .col-sm-4,
   >   .col-sm-5,
   >   .col-sm-6,
   >   .col-sm-7,
   >   .col-sm-8,
   >   .col-sm-9,
   >   .col-sm-10,
   >   .col-sm-11 {
   >     float: left;
   >     margin-left: 3.1518624641834%;
   >     *margin-left: 2.0744680851064%;
   >   }
   > ....
   > }
   > ```
2. I reset the margin-left of -12 (100% wide) columns only, again inside each media query.

   > ```
   >   .col-sm-12 {
   >     width: 100%;
   >     *width: 99.946808510638%;
   >     margin-left: 0;
   >   }
   > ```
3. the important thing to recall is you shouldn't have any margin-left declarations outside media queries.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to setup a custom media query with max-width as opposed to the usual min-width, and give it a `margin-left:0px;` like so:

```
@media (max-width: 1169px){
  .row .col-md-12{
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Applying this rule will set to 0 all margins of divs which contain the class col-md-12.. So I won't have any gutters anymore...

Comment: so add another class in there... i.e. ".row .col-md-12 .custom {..." and also add that class to the single place in your HTML you need to use it.

Comment: you didnt get it.. this is not a one time exception, this is a generic situation that can happen with any nested element in any layout, of any kind...

Comment: what if you used percentage based padding instead of margin, and used the built-in .row margin-offset to bring the left and right content inline?

Comment: I just put my answer back to it's original form, because it occured to me that your initial concern is not an issue. This rule only sets col-md-12 to left-margin:0 when below 1170px wide, i.e. when its full width. You obviously don't need a gutter when at full width. Once above 1170px, the media query disables the margin and it reverts to your original setup.