# Bootstrap Space between Listing Item

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Add margin, padding or even space between 2 list items which uses bootstrap by default.

Tried Topics

1. [Space between bootstrap columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42229931/space-between-bootstrap-columns)

Here is the image attached

[image]

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ssuryar/n564yhz0/4/)

```
<div class="container text-left">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12">
                  <!-- Nav tabs -->
                  <ul class="nav nav-justified" id="nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                      <li role="presentation" class="active">
                          <a href="#" aria-controls="" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                              <img class="img" src="https://images.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
                              <span class="quote"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i></span>
                          </a>
                      </li>
                      <li role="presentation" class="">
                          <a href="#" aria-controls="" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                              <img class="img" src="https://images.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
                              <span class="quote"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i></span>
                          </a>
                      </li>

                  </ul>
              </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post the code that you've tried.

Comment: what do you really want to do

Comment: Ah, the magic spacing between list items. I also was never able to figure out where this came from, so I decided to use flex instead.

Comment: @Thomas Yates - Working with table-cell, flex won't help

Comment: @SuryaRPraveen oh it actually seems as if I misunderstood. I was talking about magic padding which is already between list items using the Bootstrap classes. But you wanted padding. My bad ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are using table-cell so applying `border-spacing: 10px;` or `border-spacing: 10px 0;` should work for you

```
.nav-justified {
      border-spacing: 10px 0;
      border-collapse: separate;
}
```

see your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n564yhz0/5/)
[image]