# Bootstrap spacing for columns

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create spacing between my bootstrap columns, but it doesn't seem to be doing it automatically. Is there a specific way or class that I need to be adding to the columns?

```
<div class="row row_padding">
 <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
  <div class="col-sm-11">1</div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
  <div class="col-sm-11">2</div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
  <div class="col-sm-11">3</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can add padding/margin for individual col-sm-4

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738712/twitter-bootstrap-grid-system-spacing-between-columns or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179644/how-to-keep-space-between-three-columns-in-bootstrap

Comment: have you considered learning [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) instead of using table-like markup?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center bdr">
    <div class="col-xs-4 m-1 p-1 w-25 border border-secondary">#1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 w-25 m-1 p-1 border border-secondary">#2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 m-1 p-1 w-25 border border-secondary">#3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When applies the column system no longer works, I'm unable to have three "col-sm-4" without it dropping onto a new line.

Comment: @AG_BOSS do you think you have applied the CSS successfully? Also let us know what is this property `top-margin: 25px;`. I am wondering how this answer got one up-vote.

Comment: OP wants space between each. Just apply border for your div and check it out.

Comment: Please take a look at this screenshot - https://imgur.com/a/fHDN15Q. I've added the code but I need spacing between each white column which doesn't seem to be applying still.

Comment: It's exactly the same as you've provided above, just with contained inside a row.

Comment: But there is a slight difference, let me see.

Comment: @Jordan now check

Comment: I found a better solution, this could potentially be better for you as well, see what you think? Update code above.

Answer (score 0):

I think `col-md-offset` or same like that classes will work for you. :-)

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me. The class is: col-md-offset-4

Comment: @Jordan col-md-offset should be matched with your column size, let’s say you use col-xs-2 for your div column then you can you col-xs-offset-4 or something that total 12.

Comment: @salmanwebdevelper it should be col-md-offset-[1-12] and it varied between xs, sm, md, and lg. ;)