# bootstrap columns and padding not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i'am new with bootstrap , i wanted to have a specific organisation of my view , you can see it in the image , but the problem is i can't manage to have padding between my cols .

```
            <div class="container">

                 <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-sm-3" style='border-radius: 5px;border: 2px solid green;'>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12" style='border-radius: 5px;background-color:red;height:70px;'></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12" style='border-radius: 5px;background-color:red;height:140px;'></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12" style='border-radius: 5px;background-color:red;height:140px;'></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12" style='border-radius: 5px;background-color:red;height:140px;'></div>                             

                    </div></div>    

                    <div class="col-sm-9" style='border-radius: 5px;border: 2px solid red;'>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4 " style='border-radius: 5px;background-color:red;height:220px;'></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4" style='border-radius: 5px;background-color:red;height:220px;'></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4" style='border-radius: 5px;background-color:red;height:220px;'></div>          

                    </div>  </div>  

                </div>


            </div>
```

and here is what i want to have and what i got with this code.

[image]

[image]

please help me with that :)
thanks

Comment: You will not receive any answer where the classes are not changed.You are asking a question without enough research.

Answer (score 1):

try this code and see if it suffices

```
<style>
        .inner {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 1em;
        }

        .horcols-4.col-sm-3 {
            margin: 1.5em;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="outer row">

            <div class="col-sm-3" style='border-radius: 5px;border: 2px solid green;'>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12" style='border-radius: 5px;background-color:red;height:70px;'></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12" style='border-radius: 5px;background-color:red;height:140px;'></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12" style='border-radius: 5px;background-color:red;height:140px;'></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12" style='border-radius: 5px;background-color:red;height:140px;'></div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-9" style='border-radius: 5px;border: 2px solid red;'>
                <div class="inner row">
                    <div class="horcols-4 col-sm-3 " style='border-radius: 5px;background-color:red;height:220px;'></div>
                    <div class="horcols-4 col-sm-3" style='border-radius: 5px;background-color:red;height:220px;'></div>
                    <div class="horcols-4 col-sm-3" style='border-radius: 5px;background-color:red;height:220px;'></div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for your answer , but this is not what i'am looking for , i need something to separate the columns with no impact of the column number , i mean if i'm using col-4 i need to use it i do not want to use col-3 otherwise it will look terrible

Comment: the problem with bootstrap is that if you use a 12 column grid and you take up the 12 columns then it will not leave any space for margins in this case using flexbox will be perfect

Answer (score 1):

You this, it will definetly arrange the grid as you required according to the model.

```
    <head>
        <style>
            .col-sm-12 { margin:3px; width:280px;}
            .col-sm-3 { margin: 3px; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="outer row">
                <div class="col-sm-3" style='border-radius: 5px;border: 2px solid green;'>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12" style='border-radius: 5px;background-color:red;height:70px;'></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12" style='border-radius: 5px;background-color:red;height:140px;'></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12" style='border-radius: 5px;background-color:red;height:140px;'></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12" style='border-radius: 5px;background-color:red;height:140px;'></div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8" style='border-radius: 5px;border: 2px solid red;'>
                    <div class="inner row">
                        <div class="horcols-4 col-sm-3 " style='border-radius: 5px;background-color:red;height:220px;'></div>
                        <div class="horcols-4 col-sm-3" style='border-radius: 5px;background-color:red;height:220px;'></div>
                        <div class="horcols-4 col-sm-3" style='border-radius: 5px;background-color:red;height:220px;'></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1" >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this one > [twitter bootstrap grid system. Spacing between columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738712/twitter-bootstrap-grid-system-spacing-between-columns), they have managed to answer this question.

**also try this one:** it renders space without adding extra divs.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="col-md-12">
     Some Content.. 
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="col-md-12">
     Some Second Content.. 
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

This will automatically render some space between the 2 divs.

Comment: how sad, @NedalJedidi sir have you tried here >  [ col-md-offset-*](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) , the link above did it provide something?