# Bootstrap Add Space between Columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have closely followed [the most popular example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738712/twitter-bootstrap-grid-system-spacing-between-columns) of how to add space between columns, but it doesn't work. You can view it in action at

[codepen.io](http://codepen.io/maudulus/pen/ozxbNB)

What I've done is put a `col-sm-12` inside of a `col-sm-4` for each column. According to the [most popular answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738712/twitter-bootstrap-grid-system-spacing-between-columns) this should automatically render some space between the 2 divs.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row blocks-grid">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 item">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <img src="http://example.com/1MBVDF4">
      <h2>This is me</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 item">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <img src="http://example.com/1MBVDF4">
      <h2>This is me</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 item">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <img src="http://example.com/1MBVDF4">
      <h2>This is me</h2>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  background: #BEB7A4;
}
.blocks-grid {
  max-width:75.0rem; 
  margin:0 auto;
  .item {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom:1rem;
    position:relative;
    height:34.0rem;
    padding-top:2.5rem;
    background:#FFFFFC;
    &:hover {
      background:#FF0000;
      color:white;
      img {
        display:none;
      }
    }
    h2 {
      font-size:2.0rem;
      margin-top:1rem;
      text-align: center;
    }    
    img {
      max-width: 100%;
      margin:auto;
      display:block;
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, I would think the result would look like the following photo, but it does not:

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a solution to apply only on some columns or all columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:  [Demo](http://codepen.io/pradeeppansari/pen/jrqWxN)

Add your "item" class with "col-sm-12"

```
body {
  background: #BEB7A4;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes on your code.

**HTML**

> Note the `subitem` class added to `col-sm-12` divs.

```
<div class="row blocks-grid">
  <div class="col-sm-4 item">
    <div class="col-sm-12 subitem">
      <img src="image_url">
      <h2>This is me</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 item">
    <div class="col-sm-12 subitem">
      <img src="image_url">
      <h2>This is me</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 item">
    <div class="col-sm-12 subitem">
      <img src="image_url">
      <h2>This is me</h2>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

**LESS**

```
body {
  background: #BEB7A4;
}
.blocks-grid {
  max-width:75.0rem; 
  margin:0 auto;
  .item {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom:1rem;
    position:relative;
    height:34.0rem;
    padding-top:2.5rem;
    .subitem {
      background:#FFFFFC;
      height: 100%;
      padding-top: 50px;
      &:hover {
        background:#FF0000;
        color:white;
        img {
          display:none;
        }
      }
      h2 {
        font-size:2.0rem;
        margin-top:1rem;
        text-align: center;
      }    
      img {
        max-width: 100%;
        margin:auto;
        display:block;
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

Take a look: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgzVRK

Hope it can helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually remove all the extra junk and let bootstrap do it for you... NEVER change margins / widths on the framework. This is all you need....

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250">
    <h2>This is me</h2>
  </div> 
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    <h2>This is me</h2>
</div>  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    <h2>This is me</h2>
  </div>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
img { width: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to move the class item from `col-xs-6` to `col-sm-12`

The snippet:

```css
body {
        background: #BEB7A4;
    }

    .blocks-grid {
        max-width: 75.0rem;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .blocks-grid .item {
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        position: relative;
        height: 34.0rem;
        padding-top: 2.5rem;
        background: #FFFFFC;
    }

    .blocks-grid .item:hover {
        background: #FF0000;
        color: white;
    }

    .blocks-grid .item:hover img {
        display: none;
    }

    .blocks-grid .item h2 {
        font-size: 2.0rem;
        margin-top: 1rem;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .blocks-grid .item img {
        max-width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <style>
        body {
        background: #BEB7A4;
    }

    .blocks-grid {
        max-width: 75.0rem;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .blocks-grid .item {
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        position: relative;
        height: 34.0rem;
        padding-top: 2.5rem;
        background: #FFFFFC;
    }

    .blocks-grid .item:hover {
        background: #FF0000;
        color: white;
    }

    .blocks-grid .item:hover img {
        display: none;
    }

    .blocks-grid .item h2 {
        font-size: 2.0rem;
        margin-top: 1rem;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .blocks-grid .item img {
        max-width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row blocks-grid">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
        <div class="col-sm-12  item">
            <img src="https://www.samhober.com/howtofoldpocketsquares/Flat1.jpg">

            <h2>This is me</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
        <div class="col-sm-12 item">
            <img src="https://www.samhober.com/howtofoldpocketsquares/Flat1.jpg">

            <h2>This is me</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
        <div class="col-sm-12 item">
            <img src="https://www.samhober.com/howtofoldpocketsquares/Flat1.jpg">

            <h2>This is me</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```