# How to create white space between columns without left and right gutter?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to create a specified amount of space between columns. So I created this based on [the answers I already had](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57124328). But this has an overflow to the right. I want to eliminate this overflow itself because I can't specify `overflow: hidden` due to interference of other components:

```css
.row {
  margin: 0 -25px;
}

.col {
  padding: 0 25px;
  min-width: 0;
}

div {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="w-100 p-3 border bg-light">Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="w-100 p-3 border bg-light">Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also saw this Pen: https://codepen.io/frouo/pen/OqGaWN

Comment: I also saw this Pen: https://codepen.io/frouo/pen/OqGaWN

Answer (score 0):

Take a parent div and give a css to them

Here your html code with a parent div 'content-div'

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
            <div class="content-div">
                <div class="w-100 p-3 border bg-light">Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text</div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
            <div class="content-div">
                <div class="w-100 p-3 border bg-light">Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text</div>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content-div {
  padding: 0 25px;
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

> Note: Try to avoid assign css to bootstrap classes

Answer (score 0):

I removed the first and last padding in addition to no-gutters. This can be done, but please let me know if there is a better way to fit the Bootstrap design!

```css
div {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

[class^="col-"]:first-child>div {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}

[class^="col-"]:last-child>div {
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="w-100 p-3 border bg-light">Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="w-100 p-3 border bg-light">Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="w-100 p-3 border bg-light">Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```