# How to put different margins width between targeted columns without my column starting a new line? (I want to keep a total of 12 col)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/yoq16fah/) is the JSFiddle link to the code.

I want to put different vertical margin width between targeted columns.
I already tried to put margin between my `col-xs-4` and `col-lg-4` by putting `mr-4`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4 col-xs-4 col-lg-4 mr-4">Logo</div>
              <div class="col-8 col-xs-8 col-lg-8">Titre</div>
          </div>
```

But the column don't fit anymore in XS mode, and in LG mode the column go to the next line.
I need to do the same as this images in responsive XS and LG :

[Mobile(XS)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEcc4.png)

[Desktop(LG)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuOtk.png)

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57124328/5638869)
you can give the parent a negative margin `mx-n*`, and the children a positive padding `px-*` e.g.

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row  mx-n2">
        <div class="px-2  col-4 col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="p-3 border bg-light">Logo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="px-2  col-8 col-xs-8 col-lg-8">
            <div class="p-3 border bg-light">Titre</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s9d1eh45/)