# how to give a gap between a flex element without breaking the breakpoint in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-5

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

soo, if I add margin to the first element like margin right : 1px. the next element go below the first element.

how to give space between the element without inflicting the breakpoint.
thanks, sorry for bad English

Comment: try adding padding. i don't think bootstrap col classes have any paddings. so it won't break the responsiveness.

Comment: thanks sir for the reply, but if I add padding.. the element still doesn't have space between the other element, it's only give space to the content inside.

Answer (score 0):

duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738712/how-to-add-spacing-between-columns).

in summary the best approach for your case is to surround your content with a div that has `col-md-12`  or to have more control simply use padding instead of margin.

**Sol #1:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        CONTENT
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        CONTENT
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Sol #2:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="p-1">
        CONTENT
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="p-2">
        CONTENT
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```